# Testing handlers that use Gorilla/context

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm using gorilla/context in a web app. The example in the docs looks like:

```
func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //...

    val := context.Get(r, foo.MyKey)

    //...
}
```

How can I unit test a handler that works like this? The only way I've managed so far is to use the context package inside my tests. I'm thinking at the moment that I could inject a context parameter into the handler but then I'm not conforming to the HandlerFunc interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic [cross-cutting concerns](http://cyrille.martraire.com/2009/12/your-crosscuttingconcerns-are-someone-else-core-domai/) example.

You are using a 3rd party to magically handle input params for your unit under test.  By that very definition, you are going to have to do some extra setup to prep the `context` for the state you want.

When it comes to Go http handlers (which the convention is to KISS it), you shouldn't need to "reach out of context" of your func to get extra data: keep all the data you need within your single func.

Personally, I try to avoid corrupting my handlers like this.  I think I've only used gorilla's context once out of the dozens of big sites I've built.  And that was basically to get around a cached response, just to keep the data refesh to the end user.  Of which I simply ignored in my unit tests, as it was out-of-scrope of what I was testing.

Instead, I use middle-ware wrappers to setup the basics I want in my handles and modify the handler's signature accordingly.

- caching
- logging
- authentication and authorization
- json marshaling
- context (e.g. expected User{} object loaded from DB)

...etc.  I would create a middle-ware that wraps your handler when you register it with `mux` that uses gorilla/context to lookup your cookie or userid or something, hidrates that user object from cache, DB, redis, etc, and then calls your handler that would have a signature like:

```
func MyHandler(u User, p Page, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // u is the User object loaded from middle-ware

    // p is your global Page object... etc
}
```

That way, your unit tests inject only the items you need under test.

And you can integration test your middle-ware on a QA server with expected User and Page objects in a datastore.

Comment: I think we're working along the lines of what you're saying. At the minute we chain middleware functions that get the required data from the request and set it to the context. Instead of accessing the context package directly inside the handler, we should inject the values from the context into the handler, is that right?

Comment: Yep, that's how we do it. keeps the handlees simple and by having the signature if the method reflect exactly what you are using within that handler.  this is how MVC frameworks in other languages define MVC routes.

Answer (score 1):

The way my team does it is to add a name to the route handler and then in the tests we call that route by name.

This is how to add a route:

`r.HandleFunc("/<route>", MyHandler).Methods("GET").Name("MyHandlerByName")`

Then this is how to test it

`r.Get("MyHandlerByName")`

Comment: I use this method for defining URLs in code, like redirects.

Answer (score 1):

One way to test handles is modify the way in which they are created. for example, Creating a function that return a http.HandlerFunc, this function can have parameters. You can mock the values that you send to the function

Without parameters

```
 func State() http.HandlerFunc {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(pResponse http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)    {
            // your code
        })
    }
```

With Parameters

```
   func State(pParam1,pParam2,pParam3 ...) http.HandlerFunc {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(pResponse http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)    {
            // your code using pParam1,pParam2,pParam3 
        })
    }
```

The mapping will be

```
http.HandleFunc("/State", State())
```

or

```
http.HandleFunc("/State", State(value1,value2,value3 ....))
```

Comment: this is middle-ware, which my answer describes. but good u had examples. :)